# Taking rows in chunks from datatable and inserting in database

Tags: c#, oracle, datatable

I have around 25k records in datatable. I already have update query written by previous developer which I can't change. What I am trying to do is as follows:

1. Take 1000 records at a time from datatable, records can vary from 1 to 25k.
2. Update query which is in string, replace IN('values here') clause of that with these 1000 records and fire query against database.

Now, I know there are effecient ways to do it, like bulk insert by use of array binding , but I can't change present coding pattern due to restrictions.
What I have tried to do:

```
 if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {

                    reviewitemsend =reviewitemsend + dr["ItemID"].ToString()+ ',';
                    //If record count is 1000 , execute against database. 
                }

            }
```

Now above approach is taking me nowwhere and am like struck. So another better aproach which I am thinking is below :

```
int TotalRecords = dt.rows.count;
If (TotalRecords <1000 && TotalRecords >0 )
 //Update existing query with this records by placing them in IN cluse and execute
else
 {
        intLoopCounter = TotalRecords/1000; //Manage for extra records, as        counter will be whole number, so i will check modulus division also, if that is 0, means no need for extra counter, if that is non zero, intLoopCounter increment by 1
for(int i= 0;i < intLoopCounter; i++)
 {
    //Take thousand records at a time, unless last counter has less than 1000 records and execute against database
}
```

}

Also, note update query is below :

```
 string UpdateStatement = @" UPDATE Table
 SET column1=<STATUS>,                                                       
 column2= '<NOTES>',
 changed_by = '<CHANGEDBY>',                                        
 status= NULL,   
 WHERE ID IN  (<IDS>)";
```

In above update query, IDS are already replaced with all 25K record ID's, which will be shown to end user like that, internally only I have to execute it as separate chunks, So within  IN() cluase I need to insert 1k records at a time

Comment: Please refer below link. I think this is what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180448/mysql-retrive-a-large-select-by-chunks

Comment: that approach is in database, I am looking for C# datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your `Datatable` using this linq method:

```
private static List<List<DataRow>> SplitDataTable(DataTable table, int pageSize)
{
    return
    table.AsEnumerable()
          .Select((row, index) => new { Row = row,  Index = index, })
          .GroupBy(x => x.Index / pageSize)
          .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Row).ToList())
          .ToList();
}
```

Then run the database query on each chunk:

```
foreach(List<DataRow> chuck in SplitDataTable(dt, 1000))
{
    foreach(DataRow row in chuck)
    {
        // prepare data from row
    }

    // execute against database
}
```

Tip: you can modify the split query to prepare your data directly inside of it (by replacing the `x.Select(v => v.Row)` part, instead of looping twice on that huge `DataTable`.

Comment: let me test it. will get back to you

Comment: Yes, it works fine and yes I optimising it to avoid looping twice