# How to dump a huge mysql table in different text/csv files based on the date column?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a huge MySQL table with millions of records. I have a use case where, based on date column, I want to split and dump the results in different text file.

For example:

```
col_1 col_2 date_col
a     b      20-12-2021 
a     b      20-12-2021 
a2    b2     21-12-2021
..    ..     ...
```

So `row1` and `row2`  will go to a CSV called `20_12_2021.csv` and `row3` will go to `21_12_2021.csv`. What I am doing right now is I am using Python to fetch results and then loop over row by row and then determine where the result will go, but it is taking a huge time.

Is there any better more optimized way to do this?

Comment: How you are reading the Tables from `MySQL ` to pandas, or you have already dumped the data into CSV and now just parsing the same ? There is nice [so post, MySQL : retrieve a large select by chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180448/mysql-retrieve-a-large-select-by-chunks)

Comment: Right now , i was bringing the results in chunksize of 1000 rows and iterating over it .

Comment: you should post your code if it doesn't have sensitive information, to get right advice or solution as i see even using `chunksize ` doesn't help to reduce memory, i've mention some references you may check them.

Comment: @KarnKumar , the codes are on my office laptop and i can't copy paste. I will try to create  a sample code . Allow me sometime.

Comment: Atif,  I uderstood.

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution, where you can use `df.groupby` with `date_col` column, which will Group DataFrame using a mapper or by a Series of columns on the axis `0` that's by default, and signifies rows.

### Solution:

```
for name, g in df.groupby('date_col'):
    g.to_csv(f'{name}.csv', index=False)

Result:

$ cat 20-12-2021.csv  <-- CSV file created

col_1,col_2,date_col
a,b,20-12-2021
a,b,20-12-2021

$ cat 21-12-2021.csv   <-- CSV file created

col_1,col_2,date_col
a2,b2,21-12-2021
```

OR

```
df.groupby('date_col').apply(lambda x: x.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(x.name), index=False))
```

Note: if you are curiosu about MYSQL efficiently for a million row then, there is a nice answer here [Pandas now has built-in support for chunked loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107953/how-to-create-a-large-pandas-dataframe-from-an-sql-query-without-running-out-of) by @ThePhysicist.

Alao look at the [Reading table with chunksize still pumps the memory](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12265)

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: since this is a huge table, wouldn't it be a problem to fit it in memory? . Since pandas dump data frames in memory.

Comment: try with `lambda` function like `df.groupby('date_col').apply(lambda x: x.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(x.name), index=False))`